# What is the difference between &GLOBAL-DEFINE and &SCOPED-DEFINE in Progress 4gl?

Tags: progress-4gl, preprocessor-directive

I understand that both are preprocessor directives, but I am unable to figure out how they are different. All that is stated in the official Progress documentation is "The syntax of the &GLOBAL-DEFINE and &SCOPED-DEFINE directives are identical but these directives are used differently." which is not very helpful.

I found one source that says that &SCOPED-DEFINE variables remain defined until the compiler finishes the current file, while &GLOBAL-DEFINE variables remain defined until the compiler finishes the current program. However, I don't quite follow what that means. This source also states that &SCOPED-DEFINE variables are propagated down the include stack, but not up it (I assume &GLOBAL-DEFINE is bidirectional?). I have tried to create a simple example but no matter what, I can't figure out the difference.

File 1: test1.p

```
{test2.i}
```

File 2: test2.i

```
&GLOBAL-DEFINE HELLO "Hello world!"
{test3.i}
```

File 3: test3.i

```
MESSAGE {&HELLO} VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Whether or not HELLO is &SCOPED-DEFINE or &GLOBAL-DEFINE, it's still defined in test3.i. So what exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you presume that global propagates upwards, which is what I found [here](https://www.progresstalk.com/threads/difference-between-global-define-and-scoped-define.110779/) when looking for an answer. However, your example only tests downward propagation. Perhaps you need this...

File 1: test1.p

```
{test2.i}
MESSAGE {&HELLO} VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
MESSAGE "{&GOODBYE}" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

File 2: test2.i

```
&GLOBAL-DEFINE HELLO "Hello world!"
&SCOPED-DEFINE GOODBYE Goodbye-cruel-world
{test3.i}
```

File 3: test3.i

```
MESSAGE {&HELLO} VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
MESSAGE "{&GOODBYE}" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

I would expect test1.p to show you `Hello world!` followed by an empty message, whereas test3.p would show you both messages in full. However I've not tried it so I may be wrong.

Comment: That example helped a lot, thanks. You were correct about when the messages would appear. One question, any reason you surrounded {&GOODBYE} with quotes? I doesn't seem to change the functionality, just curious why you did that.

Comment: I wanted to ensure you could message an empty string if the define wasn't defined. `MESSAGE   VIEW AS ALERT-BOX.` may have failed to compile.

Comment: I tested this myself, and it does work as expected in 11.6.